# .removeAttr jQuery

Tags: jquery, class

I have this piece of code below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/effects.core.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  p { cursor: pointer; font-size: 1.2em; }
  .selected { color:red; }
</style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').click(function () {
      $(this).removeClass('selected', 1000);
      $(this).removeAttr('class');
      //$(this).removeAttr('style');
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<p class="selected">Click me to remove 'selected' class.</p>
<p class="selected">Click me to remove 'selected' class.</p>
<p class="selected">Click me to remove 'selected' class.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

So when I click on any `<p>` the class does get removed and the attribute class gets removed as well. However what happens is the code style=" " gets injected into the inline of `<p>` .

Why does this happen and how do you remove it? To me after you click on a `<p>` element the new definition for `<p>` should be merely `<p>some text goes here</p>`

Comment: Why would you need or want to `.removeAttr('class')`? Or care if there's an empty `style=` attribute? It doesn't make any difference to the browser.

Comment: I agree with @Blazemonger. The `style` attribute is created by jQUI during the class animation. If you remove the second parameter of `removeClass` it works as you want (at least the code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why the style is there is because of the jquery-ui [removeclass()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/removeClass/) although its not in the documents it seems it has more arguments (see [soruce](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.effect.js#L840,L845)) that you can use to use the callback that will be running after the animation is done:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').click(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('selected', 1000, function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('style').removeAttr("class");
        });
    });
});
```

(I´m not sure why you want to do this in the first place).

a demo: http://jsbin.com/opucon/2/ (result demo)

Comment: Voigtan thanks for the answer. The reason is I was following a tutorial on adding a class and removing a class and that did work but a style=" " was added which was not there before.

Comment: @jimdif its because of the jquery-ui removeClass code, if you don´t want the animation just use one argument in removeClass as the jQuery (core) documentation shows. Nice that it works.

Comment: Ah I see now. $(this).removeClass('selected');  works perfect without the additional style=" " being created.